# Prevent operators displaying multiple times in a row in calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I made a simple calculator with pure JavaScript.

```js
function display(val) {
  document.getElementById("result").value += val;
}

function solve() {
  let x = document.getElementById("result").value
  let y = eval(x)
  
  document.getElementById("result").value = y
}

function clr() {
  document.getElementById("result").value = ""
}
```

```html
<div class="app-wrapper">
  <div class="calc-wrapper">
    <div class="calc-display">
      <input type="text" id="result">
    </div>
    <div class="button-cont">
      <div class="row row-1">
        <div class="button ac" onclick="clr()">AC</div>
        <div onclick="display('/')" class="button operator">/</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-2">
        <div onclick="display('7')" class="button digit">7</div>
        <div onclick="display('8')" class="button digit">8</div>
        <div onclick="display('9')" class="button digit">9</div>
        <div onclick="display('*')" class="button operator">*</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-3">
        <div onclick="display('4')" class="button digit">4</div>
        <div onclick="display('5')" class="button digit">5</div>
        <div onclick="display('6')" class="button digit">6</div>
        <div onclick="display('-')" class="button operator">-</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-4">
        <div onclick="display('1')" class="button digit">1</div>
        <div onclick="display('2')" class="button digit">2</div>
        <div onclick="display('3')" class="button digit">3</div>
        <div onclick="display('+')" class="button operator">+</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-5">
        <div onclick="display('0')" class="button digit zero">0</div>
        <div onclick="display('.')" class="button digit">.</div>
        <div onclick="solve()" class="button operator">=</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have some problems concerning the operators. When I type plus more than one time, I don’t want it to display more than once. The same with `/`, `*`, `-`, `+`, and `.`.

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this problem?

Comment: You should not use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). It has performance and security problems.

Comment: Well, use logic. When you type something, you're calling `display`. In that function, you have the ability to look at what's already in the `input`. So check the last character; if it's the same operator, don't add the operator to the `input`.

Comment: We get such questions almost every day. You probably also want to prevent binary operators at the start or the end of an expression, deal with float precision, deal with `eval` security, and so on. This is too broad. Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service; try to think about how you might solve this. Use the available [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) APIs.

Comment: @Mark Baijens: Why would it matter in this context? There is no server request or anything. It is just a console.

Comment: @JavaScript _“There is no server request”_ — There is an `eval`, though. An `eval` can do _everything_, including server requests.

Comment: @JavaScript I assume the OP planned to use this in a real life situation or for educational matters. In both cases it is worth notifying him about the risks of using the function since it's generally something you want to avoid.

Comment: @Sebastian Simon: Opening the devtool console can do everything as well. If people know what to write in that input field to mess around they know how to open a console.

Comment: @ScottHunter 
decimal.onclick = () => { 
    if(!document.getElementById("result").value.includes('.')) {
        document.getElementById("result").value += '.';
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = document.getElementById("result").value;
}

Comment: How does the code in your comment (which belongs in the question) supposed to handle operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a list of operators and compare it with the input value and current result.

**NOTE:** I highly recommend to get rid of the eval function due to security (and performance) issues the eval function has.

I also recommend to use javascript event handlers instead of inline event handlers.

```js
function display(val) {
  //Create a list of all operators of the calculator
  let operators = [...document.querySelectorAll('.operator')].map(el => el.textContent);
  
  //Get the current value
  let resultElement = document.querySelector('#result');
  let currentResult = resultElement.value;
  
  //When the input is an operator and the last character of the result is an operator then overwrite it, otherwise append it.
  if(operators.includes(val) && operators.includes(currentResult.charAt(currentResult.length - 1))) {
    resultElement.value = currentResult.substring(0, currentResult.length - 1) + val;
  }
  else {
    resultElement.value += val;
  }
}

function solve() {
  let x = document.getElementById("result").value
  let y = eval(x)
  document.getElementById("result").value = y
}

function clr() {
  document.getElementById("result").value = ""
}
```

```html
<div class="app-wrapper">
  <div class="calc-wrapper">
    <div class="calc-display">
      <input type="text" id="result">
    </div>
    <div class="button-cont">
      <div class="row row-1">
        <div class="button ac" onclick="clr()">AC</div>
        <div onclick="display('/')" class="button operator">/</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-2">
        <div onclick="display('7')" class="button digit">7</div>
        <div onclick="display('8')" class="button digit">8</div>
        <div onclick="display('9')" class="button digit">9</div>
        <div onclick="display('*')" class="button operator">*</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-3">
        <div onclick="display('4')" class="button digit">4</div>
        <div onclick="display('5')" class="button digit">5</div>
        <div onclick="display('6')" class="button digit">6</div>
        <div onclick="display('-')" class="button operator">-</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-4">
        <div onclick="display('1')" class="button digit">1</div>
        <div onclick="display('2')" class="button digit">2</div>
        <div onclick="display('3')" class="button digit">3</div>
        <div onclick="display('+')" class="button operator">+</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-5">
        <div onclick="display('0')" class="button digit zero">0</div>
        <div onclick="display('.')" class="button digit">.</div>
        <div onclick="solve()" class="button operator">=</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```